# Disable the option of the 2nd select box if selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have two select boxes, using select2 js plugin. Both the drop-downs have the same options. I want to disable option selected in the 2nd select box if it's selected on the first one and vice versa.

Here is the code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.minimal').select2();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="minimal" name="coin1">
  <option value="btc">btc</option>
  <option value="usd">usd</option>
  <option value="eth">eth</option>
</select>

<select class="minimal" name="coin2">
  <option value="btc">btc</option>
  <option value="usd">usd</option>
  <option value="eth">eth</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See code comments below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.minimal')
    .select2()
    .change(function() {                      // when changed
      let val = $(this).val();                // save the current value
      $('.minimal').not(this).find('option')  // grab options from other select
        .prop('disabled', function() {        // disable those equal to current value
          return $(this).val() == val;
        })
        .select2();                           // re-establish select2
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.minimal')
    .select2()
    .change(function() {
      let val = $(this).val();
      $('.minimal').not(this).find('option').prop('disabled', function() {
        return $(this).val() == val;
      }).select2();
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="minimal" name="coin1">
  <option value="btc">btc</option>
  <option value="usd">usd</option>
  <option value="eth">eth</option>
</select>

<select class="minimal" name="coin2">
  <option value="btc">btc</option>
  <option value="usd">usd</option>
  <option value="eth">eth</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I dived into the [documentation](https://select2.org/) and this should do the trick:

It's one function for both selects and it uses the `name` attribute to differ.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.minimal').select2();
});

$('select.minimal').on('select2:select', function(e) {

  let elem;
  elem = ($(this).attr("name") == "coin1") ? 2 : 1; //set the elementIndex

  //reset
  $('select[name="coin' + elem + '"] > option').removeAttr("disabled");
  $('select[name="coin' + elem + '"]').select2();

  const value = $(this).select2('data')[0].text; //select the value
  $('select[name="coin' + elem + '"] > option[value="' + value + '"]').attr("disabled", true);

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="minimal" name="coin1">
  <option value="btc">btc</option>
  <option value="usd">usd</option>
  <option value="eth">eth</option>
</select>

<select class="minimal" name="coin2">
  <option value="btc">btc</option>
  <option value="usd">usd</option>
  <option value="eth">eth</option>
</select>
```